# Copy file using last smb jcifs-ng jar

Tags: java, smb, jcifs

Trying to move from jcifs to jcifs-ng (the latest jar jcifs-ng-2.1.2.jar) to copy files to/from remote. 
My code using old jcifs:

```java
    System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.responseTimeout", "10000");
    System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.soTimeout", "2000");
    if (winsIPList.trim().equals("")) {
        System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.dfs.disabled", "true");             
    } else {
       System.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.dfs.disabled", "false");
       System.setProperty("jcifs.netbios.wins", winsIPList.trim());
       System.setProperty("resolveOrder", "DNS");
    }
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new 
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication(filesrvDomainIP, filesrvDomainUser,
                    filesrvDomainPassword);
    smbRemoteFile = new SmbFile("smb:" + remoteFile.replace("\\", "/"), auth);
    <here the code to copy file>
```

Found few examples in stackoverflow, but looks like they are old.

Part of them include usage of NtlmPasswordAuthentication(context, DomainIP, DomainUser,DomainPassword) which is deprecated in the last jcifs-ng package.

Others use

```java
SmbFile smbRemoteFile = new SmbFile(remoteFile, someContext)
```

which is reported as undefined by compiler

Could somebody provide an example that works?

Answer (score 7):

Working example:

```
BaseContext baseCxt = null;
Properties jcifsProperties  = new Properties();
jcifsProperties.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.enableSMB2", "true");
jcifsProperties.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.dfs.disabled","true");
Configuration config = new PropertyConfiguration(jcifsProperties);
baseCxt = new BaseContext(config);
auth = baseCxt.withCredentials(new NtlmPasswordAuthenticator(DomainIP, DomainUser,
                    DomainPassword));
SmbFile smbRemoteFile = new SmbFile("smb:" + remoteFile.replace("\\", "/"), auth);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this issue: [jcifs-ng Issue #36: Chicken/egg relationship between CIFSContext and credentials](https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng/issues/36)

Class `NtlmPasswordAuthentication` is replaced by `NtlmPasswordAuthenticator`.

So you might replace your `NtlmPasswordAuthentication` usage with:

```
NtlmPasswordAuthenticator auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthenticator(domain, username, password)
```

Besides, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48467145) might be helpful.